# Composition of Taylor expansions of trigonometric functions and their inverses.

Tags: taylor-expansion, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I was trying to check whether $ arc sin (sin \theta) = \theta$ and $arc cos(cos \theta) = \theta $ is satisfied when I compose Taylor series expansion of these functions, i.e.:

1. For sine:

$$ x = sin \theta = \theta - \frac{\theta^3}{3!} + \frac{\theta^5}{5!} - ... $$
$$ arc sin x = x + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} x^3 + \frac{3}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5} x^5 + ... $$

2. For cosine:

$$ x = cos \theta = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2!} + \frac{\theta^4}{4!} - ... $$
$$ arc cos x = \frac{\pi}{2} - (x + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} x^3 + \frac{3}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5} x^5 + ...) $$

What I wanted to do was to substitute $x$ in the Taylor expansion of an inverse trigonometric function with the Taylor expansion for the respective trigonometric function, group the terms according to the power of $\theta$ and check if everything different than $\theta$ term disappears.

In case of the sine function, I indeed get $\theta = arc sin (sin \theta)$ with this approach. However, in the case of cosine it seems to me that the lowest non-constant term has to be of degree 2. But then it is impossible to get $\theta$ after grouping the terms. Why is this the case? Why does this approach work for sine and does not work for cosine? Am I making a computational mistake in my reasoning or is it somehow connected to the radius of convergence for the series?

Comment: In the arcsin case, $\theta=0$ corresponds to $x=0$, so what you did worked.  But in the arccos case, $\theta=0$ corresponds to $x=1$.  So you should expand $\arccos x$ in powers of $(x-1)$, not in powers of $x$.

Comment: @GEdgar Except that $\arccos$ has a branch point at $1$, so you'd need a Puiseux series (and use different branches ...)

Comment: Hmm, maybe to clarify my question a little bit more: it seems to me that if I take the formula for $cos\theta$ and input there a number, let's say $\theta  = \frac{\pi}{4}$ I will get a number (in this case $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$). If I take the number I got and input it to the second formula, I will get $\frac{\pi}{4}$ again, right? If it's true, then why it doesn't work for the general formula?

Answer (score 1):

$\cos$ is an even function, so $g(\cos(x))$ is an even function for any function $g$.  That is, $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$, so $g(\cos(-x)) = g(\cos(x))$. Thus it is impossible to have $g(\cos(x)) = x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Puiseux series as mentioned by Robert:
$$
\arccos(x) = \sqrt{2}(1-x)^{1/2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12}(1-x)^{3/2}
+\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5\cdot 2^5}(1-x)^{5/2} + \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{7\cdot 2^7}(1-x)^{7/2} +\frac{35\sqrt{2}}{9\cdot 2^{11}}(1-x)^{9/2}
+ \dots
\tag1$$
for $-1 < x \le 1$.  If we plug
$$
x = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2!} + \frac{\theta^4}{4!} - ...
\tag2$$
into $(1)$, we should get $\theta$.  At least for $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, and with $-\sqrt{2}(1-x)^{1/2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} (1-x)^{3/2} - \ldots$ we get $\theta$ for $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le 0$.